# Please could someone check my proof that $K$ is a subgroup of $H$?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I solved the following exercise:

Let $|G|=p^nm$ where $p$ is a prime and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.Suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p^n$. If $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^k$, show that $K \subseteq H$.

> Please could someone check my proof and tell me if it is correct?

Note that this appears early in the book in the chapter on normal subgroups and way before Sylow's theorems.

Here is my proof:

If $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $K/H$ is a subgroup of $G/H$.

Also, $|K/H|=p^i$ for some $i$. Since $|G/H|=m$ it follows that $i=0$ hence $k \subseteq H$.

Comment: Almost correct. It should be $KH/H$ instead $K/H$. Then proceed in same way as you wrote. [Typo: last equation, k should be Capital]

Answer (score 1):

Your proof isn't correct, because $K/H$ has meaning, when $H \triangleleft K$. But in this case this is not happen.
You should consider $HK/H$ or use **product formula** : 
$$|KH|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$$
Since $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ , if $H\cap K\neq K$ and so $|H\cap K|=p^j\quad j<k$, and then $|KH|=\frac{p^{n+k}}{p^j}=p^{n+k-j}> p^n$ contradiction. Because $p^{n+k-j} \nmid |G|$.

Comment: What is the contradiction, please? Couldn't it be $\;|HK|=p^nm'>p^n\;,\,\,1<m'\mid m\;$ ?

Comment: @Joanpemo I thought it was clear. But I added proof.

Comment: @2ooo Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the isomorphism theorems, If the claim isn't true then $\;K\cap H\neq K\;$ , but

$$KH/H\cong K/\left(H\cap K\right)\implies KH/H\;\;\text{is a $\;p\,-$ subgroup of }\;\;G/H$$

and thus $\;p\,\mid\,\left|G/H\right|=m\;$ , contradiction. Thus, $\;K\cap H=K\iff K\le K\;$ and we've finished

Answer (score 0):

by division alogorithm for some integers $s,t$ such that  $1=ms+p^kt$.let $x$ belong to $K$ then . $xK$ is an element of group $G/H$ whose order is $m$. so $x^mH=H$ hence $x^m$ is in $H$. so $x^{ms}=x^{1-yP^k}$ is in $H$. As $x$ is an element of $k$ ,$x^{p^k}=1$ . Proving that $x$ is in $H$